# How do i run scheduler every 12 Hours using Cron Job manager nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cron, job-scheduling

Currently I am using below code to run it every 12 hours :

```
var CronJobManager = require('cron-job-manager');
var manager = new CronJobManager();
manager.add('job123', '0 */12 * * *', function () { 
    console.log('tick1...');
});
manager.start('job123');
```

and using following repo:

https://github.com/cfurst/CronJobManager

Comment: You are running the cron every 2 hours, you need to use 0 */12 * * *

Comment: Sorry it was typing mistake, problem is same

Comment: What issue are you having exactly? Does it not run at all? Do you get any issues when starting your server?

Comment: does not starting scheduler at a time when i start server. it is wait till 12 hours.

Comment: Thats not how cron jobs work, crons are setup to run at a specific time of the day. You would need to initiate your script when the sever starts.

Comment: You means it can not run every 12 hours from when i start it ?

Comment: No, if you set a cron to run every 12 hours (*/12) it will run at midday and midnight. I suppose you could write a script that looks at the time when you started the script and adds 12 hours on to it and adjusts the cron job dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @Tony for your response, it will be very help full if you could Give Code snippet  to run cron job every 12 hours from when i start the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attempt to get the current hour the script is initated and then setup a cron to run from that hour and that hour +12

```
var CronJobManager = require('cron-job-manager');
var manager = new CronJobManager();
var d = new Date();
var d12 = d.getHours()+12;
if (d12 > 23) {
    d12 = d12-24;
}

// run your function here

console.log('The cron is setup to run at '+d.getHours()+' and '+d12+' hours!');

manager.add('job123', '0 '+d.getHours()+','+d12+' * * *', function () {
    console.log(d.getHours())

    // run your function here

});
manager.start('job123');
```

You will also need to initaite the script you want to run first.

Let me know if this has helped you.

Comment: Thank you @Tony, seems like it should work. let me implement it.